# basic XSD importing and xsd.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd.exe

I have a main xsd built against another one containing shared types (they are in the same directory).

That's the header of the main one :

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:tns="XMLSchema_Module.xsd"
      xmlns:cs="XML_Common"
      targetNamespace="XMLSchema_Module.xsd"
      elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:import schemaLocation="XML_Common.xsd" namespace="XML_Common"/>
```

That's the header of the shared types one :

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="XML_Common"
      elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

That's the shared type enumeration I want to use in an attribute of the main schema :

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="TypesType">
    <xsd:restriction base ="xsd:token">
      <xsd:enumeration value="int"/>
```

And here is the reference in the main one :

```
 <xsd:attribute name="Type" type="cs:TypesType"/>
```

I am using xsd.exe to generate the serialization classes (integrated in the build process as a pre-build event). These xsd were built using VisualStudio.

```
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\xsd.exe&quot; XSchemas\XMLSchema_Module.xsd /c /o:SerializationClasses /n:ScenarioManager" />
```

I am translating the actual message I obtain :

```
The type XML_Common:TypesType is not declared or is not a simple type.
```

It seems to be an import problem but I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My bad, it seems that xsd.exe does not resolve schema imports.
From [this article](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.fr/2010/05/correctly-creating-classes-using-xsdexe.html) :

> Now that the type has been defined in another file, the xsd.exe will
>   generate this error if you attempt to create the create the Request
>   XML: C:\Solution\Project>xsd.exe Request.xsd /c Schema validation
>   warning: Type 'http://www.Example.com/Types:Meeting' is not declared. 
>   Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or
>   may produce incorrect results.  Error: Error generating classes for
>   schema 'C:\Solution\Projects\Request'.
>
> - The datatype 'http://www.Example.com/Types:Meeting' is missing.  If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?". This is due to the
>     fact that the xsd.exe does not use the schemaLocation hint to find the
>     imported schema. You’ve got to include it as a parameter. in your
>     xsd.exe call: C:\Solution\Project>xsd.exe Types.xsd Request.xsd /c

Answer (score 2):

It should be emphasized that despite the pessimistic opening of LB40's answer, its  last sentence yields the solution: in your xsd.exe call you have to include the referenced xsd as a parameter **before** the referencing xsd:

C:\Solution\Project>xsd.exe Types.xsd Request.xsd /c

This will generate a single cs source file containing the classes for both the schemas.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.